Derived set of a closed subspace
Suppose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff topological space with a basis of clopen sets. Let $A$ be a closed subspace of $X$ and let $A^{(0)}=A$, $A^{(1)}=A^\prime$, etc. My question is: it is true that $A^{(n)}=A\cap X^{(n)}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?
Since $A\subset X$, then $A^{(n)}\subset X^{(n)}$. Also, since $A$ is closed, one can prove by induction on $n$ that $A^{(n)}\subset A$. These two things together prove one of the directions of the problem. But I can’t prove that $A\cap X^{(n)}\subset A^{(n)}$.

What is $A'$? I'm unfamiliar with this notation in topology.

In my experience, $A'$ is the set of accumulation points / limit points, sometimes also called the derived set.

@PrincessEev Ah, gotcha.

What if $X$ is perfect and $A$ is not?

Remember to accept one of the answers if you find it satisfactory.

So, here's a counterexample: take the space $X = (\omega + 1)^2$. It is clearly hausdorff, compact, and has a basis of clopen sets. Now, take $A = (\omega + 1) \times \{\omega\}$. We have $A^{(2)} = \emptyset$, but $X' = (\omega + 1) \times \{\omega\} \cup \{\omega\} \times (\omega + 1)$, and thus $X^{(2)} \cap A = \{\omega\} \times \{\omega\}$.
Edit: Actually, there's not even a need to go to the 2nd step. $X' \cap A = A \not \subset A' = \{\omega\} \times \{\omega\}$ is already a valid counterexample.

$X=\omega+1$ and $A={\omega}$ would work just as well.

What if $A$ is not only a closed set but a clopen set? Does my question have affirmative answer? I think so, but I’m not sure.

@Earnur If A is clopen, then any deleted neighbourhood of a point in A can be intersected with A to get another deleted neighbourhood, which proves your theorem.

An easy counterexample: just take $X$ to be the Cantor set and $A$ be a singleton in $X$.
